# No puedo generar un pdf con mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdf

Tengo un problema con mi proyecto quiero generar un pdf pero tengo el error de que no me muestra nada, puse el echo 1 para ver si entraba al primer si que es para saber si la sesión esta iniciada y si me muestra el 1 pero en le siguiente si para ver si entra quiero imprimir el 2 y no me lo muestra asi que supongo que esta mal estructurada la consulta o simplemente por alli no va el asunto ya que al momento de no entrar al segundo si no ejecuta las líneas para generar el pdf , me gustaria que me ayudaran a resolver mi problema o algun otro codigo para generar mi pdf con mysql, gracias.

```
 <?php
session_start(); //si esta logeado
include "fpdf.php"; //LIBRERIA
require 'connection.php'; //agrege
$conn = Connect();
//Crear conexion
//$conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, 
$dbname) or die($conn->connect_error); 
if (isset($_SESSION['login_user2'])) {
echo("1");
$name = $_SESSION['login_user2']; 
echo("$name");
$consulta = "SELECT food_id, foodname, 
food_quantity, food_price, r_id, username FROM 
 orders WHERE username = '$name'";
if ($resultado = mysqli_query($conn, 
$consulta)) { //creo que esta mal la consulta
echo("2");
while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {
 $F_ID = $values["food_id"];
$foodname = $values["food_name"];
$quantity = $values["food_quantity"];
$price =  $values["food_price"];
$total = ($values["food_quantity"] * 
$values["food_price"]);
$R_ID = $values["R_ID"];
$username = $_SESSION["login_user2"];
$order_date = date('Y-m-d');
//total
$gtotal = $total + ($values["food_quantity"] * 
$values["food_price"]);
//se agrego 
//<h1 class="text-center">Total: $ <?php echo 
"$gtotal"; ?</h1>

//hasta aqui    
$pdf = new FPDF($orientation='P',$unit='mm', 
array(45,350));
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',8);    //Letra Arial, 
negrita (Bold), tam. 20
$textypos = 5;
$pdf->setY(2);
$pdf->setX(2);
$pdf->Cell(5,$textypos,"LE CAFE'");
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',5);    //Letra Arial, 
negrita (Bold), tam. 20
$textypos+=6;
$pdf->setX(2);
$pdf->Cell(5,$textypos,'------------------------ 
-------------------------------------------');
$textypos+=6;
$pdf->setX(2);
$pdf->Cell(5,$textypos,'CANT.  ARTICULO       
PRECIO               TOTAL');

//$total =0;
$off = $textypos+6;
$producto = array(
"q"=>$quantity,
"name"=> $foodname,
"price"=>$price
 );
$productos = array($foodname);
foreach($productos as $pro){
$pdf->setX(2);
$pdf->Cell(5,$off,$pro["q"]);
$pdf->setX(6);
$pdf->Cell(35,$off,  
strtoupper(substr($pro["name"], 0,12)) );
$pdf->setX(20);
$pdf->Cell(11,$off,  
"$".number_format($pro["price"],2,".",",") 
,0,0,"R");
$pdf->setX(32);
$pdf->Cell(11,$off,  "$    
".number_format($pro["q"]*$pro["price"],2,".",",") 
,0,0,"R");

//$total += $pro["q"]*$pro["price"];
$off+=6;
}
$textypos=$off+6;

$pdf->setX(2);
$pdf->Cell(5,$textypos,"TOTAL: " );
$pdf->setX(38);
$pdf->Cell(5,$textypos,"$ 
".number_format($total,2,".",","),0,0,"R");
$pdf->setX(2);
$pdf->Cell(5,$textypos+6,'GRACIAS POR TU COMPRA 
');

$pdf->output();
}
}
}
```

Comment: Puede que sea otra cosa, pero me parecer raro el comentario que tienes debajo de `// Crear conexión`. Parece que solo has comentado la mitad de la línea.

Comment: Resulta muy difícil leer tu código, por favor edita la pregunta y trata de indentarlo para que sea más legible.

Comment: Iba a editar tu pregunta, pero me di cuenta de algunos errores, como el que te comentó @ordago-QUÉDATEENCASA y este otro `negrita (Bold), tam. 20`, donde, suponiendo que `negrita` sea una función, _Bold_ y _tam_ no son variables, además la coma y la falta de punto y coma son muchos errores para una sola línea.